# How to initialize Runtime array with name from the list

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I have a list named
list_1 = ["File_A","File_B","File_C","File_D"]

I want to run a loop and get four arrays as

File_A = np.array(0)

File_B = np.array(0)

File_C = np.array(0)

File_D = np.array(0)

Please reply if possible

Comment: Please prepare the outputs that you want

Comment: Please give examples of input and required output

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. Edit the question to explain it with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **strongly discouraged** you to use `locals()` (or `globals()` or `vars()`) to manipulate the variables dynamically:

```
list_1 = ['File_A', 'File_B', 'File_C', 'File_D']
for v in list_1:
    locals()[v] = np.array(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> File_A
array(0)

>>> File_B
array(0)

>>> File_C
array(0)

>>> File_D
array(0)
```

**Note**: `File_A`, `File_B`, ... should be valid Python name identifiers.

Comment: Thank you. It is Working. This is what I require

Answer (score 1):

You could use dictionary objects perhaps.

```
list_1 = ["File_A","File_B", "File_C", "File_D"]


myFileLists = {}
for _file in list_1:
    myFileLists[_file] = []
```

To view an element, example the list created for 'File_A':

```
print (myFileLists['File_A'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this seems to be an ideal case for using a dictionary. For example:

```
import numpy

list_1 = ["File_A", "File_B", "File_C", "File_D"]

D = {k: numpy.array(0) for k in list_1}
```

You can then access the numpy arrays "by name" as:

```
D['File_A']
```

...and so on